# Ayuda con tamaño de Imagenes en React Native en un chat bot

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon

[image: Imagen del error]Tengo un problema con la carga de imágenes en Reac Native, estoy haciendo un proyecto de un chat bot, por ahora va bien solo que al momento de cargar la imagen del mismo me sale de una forma extraña y no se ajusta al tamaño del contenedor del chat. Dejo el código.

Como pueden ver en la imagen, al momento en que el chatbot responde, sale la palabra y la imagen de mal manera y me gustaria que se acomplara al contenedor azul o con que salga de una manera ajustada del tamaño. Si me pueden ayudar porfavor.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  Text, 
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native'
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');

// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1' // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:9e16f4a9-042a-4db5-b431-1f2942950060',
})
let lexRunTime = new AWS.LexRuntime()
let lexUserId = 'mediumBot' + Date.now()
var sessionAttributes = {};
var responseCardOptions = null;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
  },
  messages: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 20,
  },
  botImage:{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 12,
    marginTop: 12
  },
  botMessages: {
      color: 'black',
      backgroundColor: '#bdf',
      padding: 10,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 20,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      marginBottom: 0,
      borderTopRightRadius: 20,
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
      bottom: 23,
      textAlign: 'left',
      width: '75%'
  },
userMessages: {
      backgroundColor: '#40AD4D',
      color: 'white',
      padding: 10,
      marginBottom: 10,
      marginRight: 10,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
      borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
      borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
      borderTopRightRadius: 20,
      width: '65%',
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      textAlign: 'left'
  },
  textInput: {
      flex: 2,
      paddingLeft: 15
  },
  responseContainer : {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      marginTop: 20,
      marginBottom: 0,
  },
  inputContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: '#EEEFFA',
  },
})

function renderResponseCard(responseCard) {

    if (responseCard.genericAttachments && responseCard.genericAttachments.length > 0) {
        // we will render at most 1 card
        var card = responseCard.genericAttachments[0];

        // title
        var titulo = card.title;

        // subtitle
        var subTitulo = card.subTitle;

        // imagen
        var imagen = card.imageUrl;
    } 
}

export default class LinksScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
  this.state = {
          userInput: '',
          messages: [],
          inputEnabled: true,
      }
  }

// Sends Text to the lex runtime
  handleTextSubmit() {
      let inputText = this.state.userInput.trim()
      if (inputText !== '')
          this.showRequest(inputText)
  }
// Populates screen with user inputted message
  showRequest(inputText) {
      // Add text input to messages in state
      let oldMessages = Object.assign([], this.state.messages)
      oldMessages.push({from: 'user', msg: inputText})
      this.setState({
          messages: oldMessages,
          userInput: '',
          inputEnabled: false
      })
      this.sendToLex(inputText)

  }
// Responsible for sending message to lex
  sendToLex(message) {
      let params = {
          botAlias: 'xpertana',
          botName: 'Xpertana',
          inputText: message,
          userId: lexUserId,
          sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes
      }
      lexRunTime.postText(params, (err, data) => {
          if(err) {
              // TODO SHOW ERROR ON MESSAGES
          }
          if (data) {
          // capture the sessionAttributes for the next cycle
                    sessionAttributes = data.sessionAttributes;
                    // reset the responseCardOptions
                    responseCardOptions = null;
              this.showResponse(data)
          }
      })
  }

showResponse(lexResponse) {
      // we will render at most 1 card
      let oldMessages = Object.assign([], this.state.messages)
      let lexMessage = lexResponse.message;

    if (lexResponse.responseCard) {
        let imagenes = [];
        imagenes.push(
            <Image source = {{uri:lexResponse.responseCard.genericAttachments[0].imageUrl}} style={styles.botImage} resizeMethod = "scale"/>
        );

        oldMessages.push({from: 'bot', msg: lexMessage});
        oldMessages.push({from: 'bot', msg: imagenes});

    renderResponseCard(lexResponse.responseCard);

    }else if (lexResponse.message) {
        oldMessages.push({from: 'bot', msg: lexMessage})
    }
      this.setState({
          messages: oldMessages,
          inputEnabled: true 
      })
  }

renderTextItem(item) {
      let style,
          responseStyle
      if (item.from === 'bot') {
          style = styles.botMessages
          responseStyle = styles.responseContainer
      }else {
        style = styles.userMessages
        responseStyle = {}
    }
      return (
          <View style={responseStyle}>
              <Text style={style}>{item.msg}</Text>
          </View>
      )
  }
render(){
      return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={styles.messages}>
                  <FlatList 
                      data={this.state.messages}
                      renderItem={({ item }) =>    this.renderTextItem(item)}
                      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                      extraData={this.state.messages}
                  />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                  <TextInput
                      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userInput: text})}
                      value={this.state.userInput}
                      style={styles.textInput}
                      editable={this.state.inputEnabled}
                      placeholder={'Escribe aquí para hablar con Xpertana'}
                      autoFocus={true}
                      onSubmitEditing={this.handleTextSubmit.bind(this)}
                  />
              </View>
          </View>
)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esto:

```
resizeMethod = "scale"
```

Por:

```
resizeMethod = "contain"
```